# ReplaceAll regexp to match all patterns, without a specific String

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a String, and I want to replace it:

```
src="test.jpg" -> src="file://test.jpg"

src="http://xxx...." -> untouched
```

In fact I replace `src="` with `src="file://` but I don't want to replace it if it starts with `http`, e.g. `src="http`.

So I wrote this regexp to replace `src="` with `src="file://`:

```
html2.replaceAll("src=\"","src=\"file://");
```

But the problem is that this also matches `src="http`.
I didn't know how to build the regexp for this. I thought that I can make it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
html2.replaceAll("src=\"[^(http)]","src=\"file:///android_asset/verkehr/");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want a zero width negative lookahead.

```
html2.replaceAll("(src=\"(?!http://))", "src=\"file:///");
```

But beware of other protocols such as https, ftp etc.

Answer (score 2):

you want a negative look ahead.
    html2.replaceAll("src=\"(?!http)",,....

Answer (score 2):

Use regex with negative lookahead:

```
 src=\"(?!http://)
```